# In Lyx, I am trying to create a module for "Illustration"

Tags: lyx, mdframed, lyx-layouts

I am trying to create `Illustration` drop down in Lyx. For this I am creating a module in the lines of `theorems-ams-bytype.module` and `theorems-ams-bytype.inc`.

This is the code inside it:

```
Style Example
CopyStyle             Definition
LatexName             example
LabelString           "Illustration \theexample."
Preamble
 \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{example}{\protect\examplename}[chapter]
EndPreamble
Requires              amsthm
LangPreamble
  \providecommand{\examplename}{_(Illustration)}
EndLangPreamble
BabelPreamble
  \addto\captions$$lang{\renewcommand{\examplename}{_(Illustration)}}
EndBabelPreamble
LabelCounter          example
End
```

What should be done in the code so that I will be able to get a nice `tikz` box or using `mdframe` some gray rounded box around the `illustration` box.

Right now the illustration looks like a example (coming from `theorem` style) but I want it should look like the concept box below.

[image]

Comment: Friends please let me know if the current problem is not clear the way I have posed. Any comments in that direction are also going to be helpful for me to get this work done.

Answer (score 1):

Here a suggestion of code. I have no experiences with Lyx.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\mdtheorem[roundcorner=5pt,backgroundcolor=gray!10,
 shadow=true,frametitlerule=true,
 middlelinewidth=1pt,frametitlerulewidth=1pt,
innertopmargin=\topskip,
apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfbackground/.append style={left color=gray!10!white,right color=white},
mdfframetitlebackground/.append style ={left color=white,right color=gray!10!white}}}]{concept}{Concept}

\begin{document}    

\begin{concept}
If $a^m=a^n$ then $m=n$ or $a=1$ or $a=-1$ and $m$, $n$ are even integers.
\end{concept}
\end{document}
```

[image]